# iOS Audio how can I make tremolo or vibrato effects

Tags: ios, audio

How can I make tremolo or vibrato audio effects in APP on iOS 8+?

I am working on making audio effects in an APP on iOS 8+ by AVFoundation provided by Apple. And I have built up some effects by AVAudioEngine, such as pitch-shift, delay(echo), distortion. But I did not find AVAudioUnit related to tremolo or vibrato effects.

The only document I have found is [Audio Unit Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/AudioUnitProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html), but this document is no longer being updated, and the Core Audio SDK mentioned in that document disappeared.

I don't care about using high level APIs belonged to AVFoundation or low level APIs even written in c/c++, I just want some method to make tremolo or vibrato effects, or generally speaking, if there is no capsulated APIs, find out one method to make customized audio effects.

By the way, here is my sample code to make delay(echo) effects 
(iOS 8+, Xcode 10.0):

```
...

if(!self.avAudioEngine.running) {
    NSLog(@"AVAudioEngine is not running!");
    return;
}

// reset all the nodes
[self.avAudioEngine reset];

// attach node
if(!self.avAudioUnitDelay) {
    self.avAudioUnitDelay = [[AVAudioUnitDelay alloc] init];
}
[self.avAudioEngine attachNode:self.avAudioPlayerNode];
[self.avAudioEngine attachNode:self.avAudioUnitDelay];

// connect node
if(!self.avAudioMixerNode) {
    self.avAudioMixerNode = [self.avAudioEngine mainMixerNode];
}

[self.avAudioEngine connect:self.avAudioPlayerNode to:self.avAudioUnitDelay format:nil];
[self.avAudioEngine connect:self.avAudioUnitDelay to:self.avAudioMixerNode format:nil];

// parameters
self.avAudioUnitDelay.delayTime = 0.02;
self.avAudioUnitDelay.feedback = 80;
self.avAudioUnitDelay.wetDryMix = 90;

// play
[self.avAudioPlayerNode scheduleFile:self.soundFile atTime:nil completionHandler:nil];
[self.avAudioPlayerNode play];
...
```

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Try this one

```
import UIKit
import AudioToolbox

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(SystemSoundID(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate))            
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, and to be more specifically, I need a to build up a APP that can do some audio effects on sound file like 'm4a'

Comment: Yes, I can play the 'm4a' and some other file, but not only play some sound effect from system. I want to change the original sound effect as guitar mixer. Usually I need to do some digital signal processing, but now, I found that Apple do not support low level API or SDK (core audio SDK) any more

Comment: Thank you very much, I will check it out.

Comment: @Tao please mark as right answer if your ans. is satisfy